# How to make the first occurrence of a number into NaN within a group

Tags: r

I'm currently trying to make the row of the first time a subject selects the blue cue into NaN in R. How do I replace the value of the first occurrence of a value within a group (the subject group) with NaN? I tried to do the following:

```
replacefirsts<-function(x)
{
  dataless[match(unique(dataless$choice==1),dataless$choice),]==NaN;
}
data=tapply(data$sID,list(data$sID),replacefirsts)
```

When I do this, it new dataset only has the NaN values and not the rest of the rows.

Currently my data looks like this:

```
sID   choice
1      2
1      1
1      3
1      1
1      1
2      1
2      2
2      2
2      3
2      3
3      3
3      1
3      2
3      2
3      2
```

What I would like: (the first occurrence of choice 1 within a group (sID) is NaN:

```
sID   choice
1      2
1      NaN
1      3
1      1
1      1
2      NaN
2      2
2      1
2      3
2      3
3      3
3     NaN
3      2
3      2
3      2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way via base R,

```
with(df, ave(choice, sID, FUN = function(i) replace(i, which(i == 1)[1], NaN)))
 #[1]  2 NaN  3  1  1 NaN  2  2  3  3  3 NaN  2  2  2
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks so much!! (and sorry for the late reply!)

Comment: What does the [1] represent?

Comment: The first observation

Answer (score 1):

Here is the dplyr way, using `group_by`

```
dat <- data.frame(sID = rep(1:3, each=3), choice = c(1,2,1,1,2,3,3,1,1))

dat %>% 
  group_by(sID) %>%
  mutate(choice2 = ifelse((choice == 1 & !duplicated(choice == 1)), NaN, choice))

Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
Groups: sID [3]

    sID choice choice2
  <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1      1     NaN
2     1      2       2
3     1      1       1
4     2      1     NaN
5     2      2       2
6     2      3       3
7     3      3       3
8     3      1     NaN
9     3      1       1
```

Comment: This is great! It works! Thanks so much for your help! Sorry for the late reply!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, .I[seq_len(.N) == 1 & choice == 1],.(choice, sID)]$V1, choice := NaN][]
#    sID choice
# 1:   1      2
# 2:   1    NaN
# 3:   1      3
# 4:   1      1
# 5:   1      1
# 6:   2    NaN
# 7:   2      2
# 8:   2      2
# 9:   2      3
#10:   2      3
#11:   3      3
#12:   3    NaN
#13:   3      2
#14:   3      2
#15:   3      2
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
with(df, NaN^(!duplicated(df) & choice == 1)*choice)
#[1]   2 NaN   3   1   1 NaN   2   2   3   3   3 NaN   2   2   2
```

Comment: This works! Thanks so much!! What does the '.' in front of the .I and .N represent?

Comment: @a.zhu  If you are talking about the comma `,`, the standard format for data.table is `i, j, by`.  Here the `i` i.e logical index for row is kept blank